# CsvReader does not detect binary input file

Tags: c#, parsing, csv

I'm using the [A Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) library for reading CSV files in my C# application. However I'm having some trouble with creating the `CsvReader` object.

`CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader("data.csv"), true));`

When passing a binary file to this code no exception is thrown and the input file is treated as a normal CSV file. How can I detect if the given file is a CSV file? Or at least how can I make sure that it is not a binary file?

Comment: this question is not really specific to CsvReader, if you have validation requirements then you need to code that yourself.

Comment: File extension? :) First few bytes?

Comment: @J0HN IIRC file extensions can easily be faked. checking the bytes might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting if a file is text or binary [is *hard*](http://code.google.com/p/chardetsharp/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/CharDet). It also stands to reason that the vast majority of text files are also *not* CSV. As such, I question whether this validation is worthwhile.

If the CSV reader can't detected trash inputs (perhaps when you start the parse rather than at construction), then I'd consider a different implementation. There are loads to choose from.

Here's one available in .net:

Reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and you can use [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx)

```
using (var parser =
    new TextFieldParser(@"c:\data.csv")
        {
            TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited,
            Delimiters = new[] { "," }
        })
{
    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        string[] fields;
        fields = parser.ReadFields();
        //go go go!
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for a CSV parser? So far, the link given in my question seems to be one of the most popular.

Comment: @RobertStrauch I've always had quite good results from VBs parser. See my edit.